# jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).noUiSlider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, nouislider

Please help my noUiSlider is not working

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).noUiSlider is not a function

Any kind of feedback is welcome.

```
function createSlider(name, start, low, high){
    if(start == -1)
        start = parseInt((high-low)/2);
  // The error starts on this line
    $(name).noUiSlider({
        start: start,
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': low,
            'max': high
        },
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        })
    });
    $(name).Link('lower').to('-inline-<div class="slider-tooltip"></div>', function ( value ) {
        if(value == high) value = (high-1)+'+';
        $(this).html(
            '<span>' + value + '</span>'
        );
    });
    $(name).append('<div class="slider-values">'+low+' <span>'+(high-1)+'+</span></div>')
}
```

Comment: Either forgot to include plugin file, or are trying to use it before it is loaded or path to file is wrong or loading more than one instance of jQuery in page

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i cleaned up my file but still not working and im loading only these scripts

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/nouislider.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/wNumb.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 >

Answer (score 0):

$(name) returns an array and noUiSlider init can't work with array. So instead of $(name) use $(name)[0]